# My checkbox does not appear in my CheckedTextView

Tags: android

Here is how I setup my checked text view. How come no check box appeared?

I also added this but it had not effect:
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

```
 <CheckedTextView
 android:id="@+id/ctv_checktext"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="2px"
 android:paddingRight="2px"
 android:paddingTop="2px"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

(I'm answering my own question because it's undocumented in the Android API)

This is not enough:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

You need to include the android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
or else

```
 <CheckedTextView
 android:id="@+id/ctv_checktext"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="2px"
 android:paddingRight="2px"
 android:paddingTop="2px"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
 />
```

Comment: The CheckedEditText documentation defines the [related method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#attr_android:checkMark). For this example: `checkedEditText.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple);`

Answer (score 1):

you can have your own checkbox.xml in drawable folder
then you can write it as android:checkMark = "@drawable/checkbox"