# CheckBox is Disapearing in fragment linearlayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
              android:background="#9999"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#336699"
            android:layout_height="53dp" android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="옛 지도"
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="385dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#475369"
              android:divider="#535975"
              android:id="@+id/navigation_list"
              android:dividerHeight="0.7dp"/>

</LinearLayout>




  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
            mDrawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);

            mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });
            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[]{
                            getString(R.string.title_map),
                            getString(R.string.title_friends),
                            "Test"
                    }));
            mDrawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            return rootView;
        }
```

onCreateView method like this

when i return mDrawerListView directly in onCreateView method ListView has "CheckBox"

but when i return rootView(contain mDrawerListView)

CheckBox is gone

setAdapter String[] array is work fine but only problem about "checkbox"

how to add check box in ListView?

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Some Title")
                    .setMessage("some message")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // Some stuff to do when cancel got clicked
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
```

in SelectItem method i can see select LOG it mean select listener work fine too

[image]

[image]

```
First Pic : when return rootView (LinearLayout)
Second Pic : when return mDrawerListView(ListView in LinearLayout)
```

Comment: What do you see - just text?

Comment: @Rob yes just listView check box is gone

Comment: @Rob I can't understand your commnet. in my case i add test log in selectItem() method and select item is work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928401/my-checkbox-does-not-appear-in-my-checkedtextview  almost looks like the drawable isn't being used

Comment: @Rob im already using  "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice," and it has android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"

Comment: @Rob checktbox doesn't appear when i add this listview to linearlayout when i use listview without linearlayout check box is appear

Comment: yes but something is going wrong....